# What do you do to verify that your network is secure?

Tags: networking, security

Securing a network can be a very difficult task.  There are a lot of ins and outs hardware and software wise (users aside!)

What steps do you take to verify that your network is secure?
What tools do you use to secure your network?
What are some of the big holes that go regularly un-fixed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We're a fairly small office and have had to manage on a small budget.  Our approach includes:

Network Intrusion Detection: 
We use StrataGuard Free from StillSecure -- it's a hardened Linux with Snort configured and a very intuitive web interface, plus regular rule updates.  Installed the free version on an old box, tuned the rules a bit based on the alerts generated, and viola!  Works great, though you need a network switch capable of mirroring traffic to a single port.  Non-free versions of StrataGuard have support, a few more bells and whistles, and can deal with higher traffic.

Host-Based Intrusion Detection:
We wrote a small .NET app that runs as a service on our Windows boxes and forwards events from the event logs every couple of hours (filtered based on types, IDs, and times of day we choose - as mentioned elsewhere, Randy Franklins Smith's site at http://www.ultimatewindowssecurity.com/Default.aspx has been invaluable in deciding what events to scrutinize) to a central database where we review and retain them.

Periodic in-house audit:
Periodically, we once-over each box, make sure all unnecessary services are disabled and ports are closed, and run deep scans with rootkit and malware detection software that's different than the real-time anti-everything running daily.  We also use nmap to analyze the network and scan for for vulnerabilities, and wireshark to analyze specific traffic as necessary.

Patch Updates:
WSUS ensures and verifies that all our windows boxes are up-to-date on security fixes, and prevents  eating up bandwidth.  Cron-apt on Linux boxes, haven't figured out a good way to verify the process centrally though.  Also, centralized management of server and workstation anti-malware is highly recommended, and available for most business-class versions of these products.

Policy:
Perhaps most importantly, even in a small organization you need to start with a document that describes a security program or set of procedures for your organization.  The document will outline the risks to your data and how you address them.  This is the big one that usually gets ignored, but should you face most any flavor of outside audit it's the first thing you'll need to refer to and wish you had or had updated.  Lots of samples on http://www.sans.org/resources/policies/.

The good news for organizations on a tight budget is that, other than the anti-malware suites, all this stuff is free, and -- with the exception of the in-house audits -- are very easy to review daily after the initial time investment to set up.

Comment: +1 for mentioning policy as being important.  Lots of people in admin positions skip it.

Answer (score 6):

These answers I'm ripping from [my response here](https://serverfault.com/questions/650/how-can-i-detect-unwanted-intrusions-on-my-servers/800#800)

- Use an IDS

  > SNORT® is an open source network intrusion prevention and detection system utilizing a rule-driven language, which combines the benefits of signature, protocol and anomaly based inspection methods. With millions of downloads to date, Snort is the most widely deployed intrusion detection and prevention technology worldwide and has become the de facto standard for the industry.

  Snort reads network traffic and can look for things like "drive by pen testing" where someone just runs an entire metasploit scan against your servers.  Good to know these sort of things, in my opinion.
- Monitor your servers - Graphs can give you a hint if something is unusual.  I use [Cacti](http://www.cacti.net/) to keep an eye on CPU, network traffic, disk space, temperatures, etc.  If something *looks* odd it *is* odd and you should find out why it's odd.  If traffic suddenly spikes in the App Tier, I'm going to want to know why.

Answer (score 4):

Seriously, depending on the size of the company your best bet might be to have a third party do regular security audits on your systems.  Higher ups like the fact that your security was independently verified, and in all seriousness, it's hard enough for most IT people to keep things working, let alone keep on top of every new security loophole.

Probably not the answer you want, but worth saying.

Answer (score 2):

- Disable universal plug-n-play
- Use Wireshark to listen for any ARP requests on the LAN from IP addresses that do not belong on the network

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand the question that you are asking.  It's like asking "Is my building secure?".  The building itself is not really "secure" or not - it just sits there.  What is really meant is "Can I always trust anyone inside the building?", and the answer is almost always "no", since you can never defend perfectly against insiders.  Likewise with networks, what you are really asking is "Can I trust that every packet I receive is genuine and that every packet I send will not be intercepted or replaced?".  This, of course, you must realize, can never be true, since you can never realistically attest the security and trustworthiness of every computer on the network.

This leaves a lack of security that must be filled by asking slightly different questions which *can* be answered affirmatively, like "Can I somehow make sure that, when I think I am sending packets to the router gateway, it really is the gateway that is receiving them and not some other host?" or "Can I make sure packets between my host and my login/file/intranet server are not intercepted and eavesdropped?".  The answers to **these** questions are "*Yes.*", since with IPsec or other technologies you *can* make sure that who you are talking to on the network really are who they say they are, and that the traffic between them is not listened to.

(You  must put out of your mind the notion that IPsec is a "VPN" technology.  It is not - it is an *encryption and authentication* technology.)