# Entries in `/etc/inittab` below last line - possible hack?

Tags: linux, hacking, rootkit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My server's been hacked EMERGENCY](https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/my-servers-been-hacked-emergency)

My Linux machine has been hacked lately.

There are a few entires in /etc/inittab below the

```
#end of /etc/inittab
```

Something like:

```
#Loading standard ttys
0:2345:once:/usr/sbin/ttyload
```

I also have serveral of the following lines:

```
2:2345:respawn:/sbin/mingetty tty2
3:2345:respawn:/sbin/mingetty tty3
.
.
.
```

I know that my `/usr/sbin/ttyload` has been hacked, and I have removed it, but I don't know if I need this is inittab, nor whether I had ttyload before. Is this file common?

Should I remove this line?

Comment: As stated below, it's hard to find out how many backdoors ae left on your system. You should perform a clean system reinstall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this line needs to be remove. It's a hacker's script that calls two infected files, etc...

[More here.](http://www.mail-archive.com/rkhunter-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg01685.html)

Answer (score 2):

That's there to reinfect the system on boot... Another part of rootkit extraction is that you're not safe until you've determined what backdoors or triggers exist to reinfect your system.

The [rpm verify command I gave in your previous question](https://serverfault.com/questions/434776/hacked-centos-5-server-possible-rootkit-installed/434789#434789) also checks configuration files to show you what's changed from the package defaults.

`rpm -vVa | grep 'S\.5\.\.\.\.\T'` will output changed binaries and configuration files (denoted by a "c")

For example:

```
S.5....T  c /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
S.5....T  c /etc/snmp/snmpd.conf
```

The "c" means that the config file changed. `rpm -qf /path/to/file` will show you the package that contains the file. You can either wipe or move the file and reinstall the rpm package to overwrite it.

Answer (score 1):

The lines with mingetty should stay there. In simple words, there are the number of console that you can access with ctrl+alt+f{1-6}. Usually the 7th is your graphical environment.

About ttyload, since it's not in your system you don't need that line.