# centos 6 ps aux hangs up

Tags: linux, kvm-virtualization

I have problem with my server. Server is running centos 6 (CloudLinux Server release 6.2).  `uname -a = 2.6.32-320.4.1.lve1.1.4.el6.x86_64` 
That is a kvm guest. On host is debian 6.

If i run command `ps aux`, it stuck on random process (shows some processes only), `top` command is working fine. `htop` doesn't work too (black screen).

```
top - 12:11:51 up 34 min,  1 user,  load average: 4.26, 6.71, 16.15
Tasks: 201 total,   7 running, 192 sleeping,   0 stopped,   2 zombie
Cpu(s):  7.9%us,  2.8%sy,  0.0%ni, 87.5%id,  1.6%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.2%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   9862044k total,  2359484k used,  7502560k free,   171720k buffers
Swap: 10485720k total,        0k used, 10485720k free,  1336872k cached
```

server has one Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5606  @ 2.13GHz,

`free -m`

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          9630       2336       7293          0        170       1324
-/+ buffers/cache:        841       8789
Swap:        10239          0      10239
```

`php -v`

```
PHP 5.3.19 (cli) (built: Nov 28 2012 10:03:07)
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
    with the ionCube PHP Loader v4.2.2, Copyright (c) 2002-2012, by ionCube Ltd., and
    with Zend Guard Loader v3.3, Copyright (c) 1998-2010, by Zend Technologies
    with Suhosin v0.9.33, Copyright (c) 2007-2012, by SektionEins GmbH
```

mysql Server version: 5.1.63-cll

`php -i`

```
disable_functions => apache_child_terminate, apache_setenv, define_syslog_variables, escapeshellarg, escapeshellcmd, eval, exec, fp, fput, ftp_connect, ftp_e
xec, ftp_get, ftp_login, ftp_nb_fput, ftp_put, ftp_raw, ftp_rawlist, highlight_file, ini_alter, ini_get_all, ini_restore, inject_code, openlog, passthru, php
_uname, phpAds_remoteInfo, phpAds_XmlRpc, phpAds_xmlrpcDecode, phpAds_xmlrpcEncode, popen, posix_getpwuid, posix_kill, posix_mkfifo, posix_setpgid, posix_set
sid, posix_setuid, posix_setuid, posix_uname, proc_close, proc_get_status, proc_nice, proc_open, proc_terminate, shell_exec, syslog, system, xmlrpc_entity_de
code, xmlrpc_server_create, putenv, show_source,mail => apache_child_terminate, apache_setenv, define_syslog_variables, escapeshellarg, escapeshellcmd, eval,
 exec, fp, fput, ftp_connect, ftp_exec, ftp_get, ftp_login, ftp_nb_fput, ftp_put, ftp_raw, ftp_rawlist, highlight_file, ini_alter, ini_get_all, ini_restore,
inject_code, openlog, passthru, php_uname, phpAds_remoteInfo, phpAds_XmlRpc, phpAds_xmlrpcDecode, phpAds_xmlrpcEncode, popen, posix_getpwuid, posix_kill, pos
ix_mkfifo, posix_setpgid, posix_setsid, posix_setuid, posix_setuid, posix_uname, proc_close, proc_get_status, proc_nice, proc_open, proc_terminate, shell_exe
c, syslog, system, xmlrpc_entity_decode, xmlrpc_server_create, putenv, show_source,mail
...
suhosin.executor.disable_eval => Off => Off
suhosin.executor.eval.blacklist => include,include_once,require,require_once,curl_init,fpassthru,base64_encode,base64_decode,mail,exec,system,proc_open,leak,
syslog,pfsockopen,shell_exec,ini_restore,symlink,stream_socket_server,proc_nice,popen,proc_get_status,dl, pcntl_exec, pcntl_fork, pcntl_signal,pcntl_waitpid,
 pcntl_wexitstatus, pcntl_wifexited, pcntl_wifsignaled,pcntl_wifstopped, pcntl_wstopsig, pcntl_wtermsig, socket_accept,socket_bind, socket_connect, socket_cr
eate, socket_create_listen,socket_create_pair,link,register_shutdown_function,register_tick_function,gzinflate => include,include_once,require,require_once,c
url_init,fpassthru,base64_encode,base64_decode,mail,exec,system,proc_open,leak,syslog,pfsockopen,shell_exec,ini_restore,symlink,stream_socket_server,proc_nic
e,popen,proc_get_status,dl, pcntl_exec, pcntl_fork, pcntl_signal,pcntl_waitpid, pcntl_wexitstatus, pcntl_wifexited, pcntl_wifsignaled,pcntl_wifstopped, pcntl
_wstopsig, pcntl_wtermsig, socket_accept,socket_bind, socket_connect, socket_create, socket_create_listen,socket_create_pair,link,register_shutdown_function,
register_tick_function,gzinflate
```

Sometimes i cannot kill httpd process. I run `kill -9 PID` even several times, and nothing happens. php runs via suphp. I learned somewhere that it can be trojan. 
I ran `strace ps aux` and it stops on

```
open("/proc/216456/cmdline", O_RDONLY)  = 5
read(5,
```

If i reboot server, problem is gone but after some time it is back again .. :(

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem was with audit: `backlog limit exceeded`
in `/etc/audit/audit.rules` i set `-b` from `320` to `9216` and problem is gone.
Thanks everyone for help :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you remote to the system? Are you connecting via SSH?

This almost seems like a fragmented packet/MTU issue somewhere between where you are and the server's location. I've seen issues with text output in those situations.

To make sure it's not your side, can you connect to the server from a different location?

How does the Debian-based host system run? Is it responsive? Other than the `ps aux`, does the system run well?

If you suspect a compromise, run some of the [steps noted here](https://serverfault.com/questions/434776/hacked-centos-5-server-possible-rootkit-installed/434789#434789) to check the system's health and verify the installed packages.

Also: [How do I deal with a compromised server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/my-servers-been-hacked-emergency)

Comment: Web pages is slow or almost unresponsive. I am connected via SSH (putty). I have another server to that subnet ( i am not sure if it is same switch) but rack is same. With another servers all is ok. MTU is 1500 and RX/TX errors is zero (booth guest and host).